# Vectorized sliding / rolling numpy nanmean

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, convolution, moving-average

I currently use this code to do a moving window average:

```
n=500

x_copy=np.hstack((np.full(n,np.nan),copy.deepcopy(x),np.full(n,np.nan)))

x_values=[]
for i in range(n,len(x)+n):
    x_values.append(np.nanmean(x[i-n:i+n+1]))

plt.plot(x_values)
```

with `x` the array I'm working on and `n` is half the length of the window. However, I need to do this quickly, as I have to do roughly 4400*10 of this operation, with arrays around `60000` elements in length. After searching for a while, I found that `np.convolve` should work, so I have this code instead:

```
plt.plot(np.convolve(x, np.ones(((2*n),))/(2*n), mode='valid'),zorder=2)
```

While this is really fast, it's not doing exactly what I need it to do, as it seems to stop `500*2` units before the end of the array. For reference, here is the image of the plots of both of them: the blue is my own code, the orange is the convolution. I want to use convolve to speed up my moving window average, though I don't know how.

[Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vfoE.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set those `NaNs` to `0s` and then use `np.convolve` on those *masked* versions -

```
# Window-size
W = 2*n+1

# Non-nans mask
m = ~np.isnan(x)

# "Masked" input array
x0 = np.where(m,x,0)

# Setup conv kernel and perform conv on x0 and mask m for the counts to divide
K = np.ones(W)
out = (np.convolve(x0,K)/np.convolve(m,K))[W-1:]
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly.

Comment: Could an approach with `np.convolve` be used for an expanding window as well?